# two-dimensional array - adding objects to fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array:

```
var test = new Array(5);
for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
 test[i]=new Array(10);
}
```

And now i want to add object to the field:

```
test[0][5].push(object);
```

But appears an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

I'm using "push" because I want to put into this field 0-4 objects but I don't know exactly how many object will be there.
How should I change it to make it correct?

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is because `test[0][5]` is returning `undefined` (since there is nothing in the array living at test[0]) and calling `push` on it. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "_I want to put into this field 0-4 objects, but I don't know exactly how many objects will be there_".

Comment: in one field can be from 0 to 4 objects

Answer (score 5):

The expression `test[0]` refers to a new Array instance, created by the line:

```
test[i]=new Array(10);
```

However, there's nothing *in* that array.  Thus, `test[0][5]` refers to an undefined object.  You'll need to initialize *that* to an array before you can `push()` something on to it.  For example:

```
test[0][5] = []; // Set [0][5] to new empty array
test[0][5].push(object); // Push object onto that array
```

Or even:

```
test[0][5] = [object]; // Set [0][5] to one item array with object
```

Comment: but this objects will be added while the app is running. I can't clear this array.

Comment: Then after you set `test[i]` to a new array, loop through that array and set each index to an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = new Array(5);
for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
  test[i]=new Array();
}
```

this will let you create a multi-dimensional array. Each element in the variable test will be an array.

From here you can do

```
test[0].push("push string");
test[0].push("push string2");
```

from here

```
test[0][1] will contain "push string2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change "<=" to "<".

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Arrays are zero based so if you have an array with 5 slots and you want to access the last slot you would use:

```
anArray[4]
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. There were too many things wrong here when I first looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

before use push ask to value is an array

```
if(test[0][5] instanceof  Array)
    test[0][5].push(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test[0][5] = new Array(); // you need initialize this position in Array
test[0][5].push(object); // and then push object
```

or

```
test[0][5] = [object]; // directly create a new Array with object
```

but if you just want to have an object in this position, you should do it:

```
test[0][5] = object;
```